# No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader)

Tags: apache, log4j, accumulo

No matter what I try, I cannot get rid of this message when attempting to start `accumulo master`

```
sh-4.2# accumulo master
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

my `log4j.properties` file is located in `/opt/accumulo/conf` - and `$ACCUMULO_HOME` seems to be configured properly;

```
sh-4.2# $ACCUMULO_HOME
sh: /opt/accumulo/: Is a directory
```

`accumulo classpath` is outputting the following;

```
sh-4.2# accumulo classpath
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [DEBUG].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /opt/hadoop/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /opt/hadoop/lib/(?!slf4j)[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/(?!slf4j)[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/jersey.*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-accumulo-handler.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:217 - ignoring classpath entry /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey.*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloClassLoader:278 - Create 2nd tier ClassLoader using URLs: [file:/opt/accumulo/conf/, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-tracer.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-examples-simple.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-test.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-monitor.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jline.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-tserver.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jcommander.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-vfs2.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-security.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-io.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-gc.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-minicluster.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-start.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-math3.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/guava.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/gson.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/libthrift.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-master.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-configuration.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-server-base.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/protobuf-java.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-util.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-server.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-core.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-shell.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/javax.servlet-api.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-fate.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-http.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-servlet.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/slf4j-api.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-proxy.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/htrace-core.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-trace.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-lang3-3.9.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.18.v20190429.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/azure-storage-8.3.0.jar, file:/opt/accumulo/lib/hadoop-azure-3.2.0.jar, file:/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.1-tests.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-kms-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-asn1-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-server-9.3.19.v20170502.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.19.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.19.v20170502.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-security-9.3.19.v20170502.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-config-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.6.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-simplekdc-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-identity-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.8.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/re2j-1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-io-9.3.19.v20170502.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.19.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-common-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/accessors-smart-1.2.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.12.0.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-crypto-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-pkix-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.19.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-xdr-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core4-4.1.0-incubating.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-admin-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/token-provider-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-server-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.12.0.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/json-smart-2.3.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.12.0.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-databind-2.7.8.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-http-9.3.19.v20170502.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-2.7.8.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/metrics-core-3.2.4.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-9.3.19.v20170502.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-xml-9.3.19.v20170502.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.19.v20170502.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-util-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-core-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-client-1.0.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-servlet-1.19.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1-tests.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-rbf-3.1.1-tests.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.1.1-tests.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-3.1.1-tests.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-rbf-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.1.1-tests.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-nativetask-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-uploader-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-services-api-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-services-core-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timeline-pluginstorage-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-router-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-3.1.1.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.19.jar, file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.19.jar]
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG SoftRefFilesCache:159 - putFile: file:///opt/accumulo/lib/ext/[^.].*.jar
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG SoftRefFilesCache:159 - putFile: file:///
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG SoftRefFilesCache:159 - putFile: file:///opt/accumulo/lib/ext
2019-06-24 00:25:31 DEBUG AccumuloReloadingVFSClassLoader:159 - monitoring file:///opt/accumulo/lib/ext
Level 1: Java System Classloader (loads Java system resources) URL classpath items are:
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
        file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar

Level 2: Java Classloader (loads everything defined by java classpath) URL classpath items are:
        file:/opt/accumulo/conf/
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-start.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/slf4j-api.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar

Level 3: Accumulo Classloader (loads everything defined by general.classpaths) URL classpath items are:
        file:/opt/accumulo/conf/
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-tracer.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-examples-simple.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-test.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-monitor.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jline.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-tserver.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jcommander.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-vfs2.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-security.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-io.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-gc.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-minicluster.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-start.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-math3.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/guava.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/gson.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/libthrift.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-master.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-configuration.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-server-base.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/protobuf-java.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-util.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-server.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-core.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-shell.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/javax.servlet-api.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-fate.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-http.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-servlet.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/slf4j-api.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-proxy.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/htrace-core.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/accumulo-trace.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/commons-lang3-3.9.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.18.v20190429.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/azure-storage-8.3.0.jar
        file:/opt/accumulo/lib/hadoop-azure-3.2.0.jar
        file:/opt/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.1-tests.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-kms-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-asn1-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-server-9.3.19.v20170502.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.19.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.19.v20170502.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-security-9.3.19.v20170502.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-config-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.6.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-simplekdc-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-identity-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.8.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/re2j-1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-io-9.3.19.v20170502.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.19.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-common-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/accessors-smart-1.2.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.12.0.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-crypto-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-pkix-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.19.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-xdr-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core4-4.1.0-incubating.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-admin-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/token-provider-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-server-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.12.0.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/json-smart-2.3.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.12.0.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-databind-2.7.8.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-http-9.3.19.v20170502.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-2.7.8.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/metrics-core-3.2.4.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-9.3.19.v20170502.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-xml-9.3.19.v20170502.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.19.v20170502.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-util-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-core-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-client-1.0.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-servlet-1.19.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1-tests.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-rbf-3.1.1-tests.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.1.1-tests.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-3.1.1-tests.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-rbf-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.1.1-tests.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-nativetask-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-uploader-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-services-api-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-services-core-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timeline-pluginstorage-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-router-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-3.1.1.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.19.jar
        file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.19.jar

Level 4: Accumulo Dynamic Classloader (loads everything defined by general.dynamic.classpaths) VFS classpaths items are:
```

My log4j.properties file, which is located in /opt/accumulo/conf, contains the following;

```
sh-4.2# cat log4j.properties
# default logging properties:
#  by default, log everything at INFO or higher to the console
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,A1

# hide Jetty junk
#log4j.logger.org.mortbay.log=WARN,A1

# hide "Got brand-new compressor" messages
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.io.compress=WARN,A1
#log4j.logger.org.apache.accumulo.core.file.rfile.bcfile.Compression=WARN,A1

# hide junk from TestRandomDeletes
#log4j.logger.org.apache.accumulo.test.TestRandomDeletes=WARN,A1

# hide junk from VFS
#log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager=WARN,A1

# hide almost everything from zookeeper
#log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,A1

# hide AUDIT messages in the shell, alternatively you could send them to a different logger
#log4j.logger.org.apache.accumulo.shell.Shell.audit=WARN,A1

# Send most things to the console
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%-8c{2}] %-5p: %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

I have been researching this issue for hours and nothing seems to be getting me any closer to a resolution. I am sure I am missing something stupid here, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can think of two possibilities. The first is file system permissions: have you verified the file system permissions for the file and all of its parent directories?
The second is possibly related to improper log4j initialization that was (will be) fixed in 2.0.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACCUMULO-3544

Comment: File System Permissions have been verified. I changed them as well just to make sure `chown -hR 1000:1000 /opt` - still I get the log4j WARN messages printed out when running `accumulo master` . From the link that you sent, where should I place the `-Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride=true` override flag? I tried putting it in the accumulo script, all the way down in the bottom with the other flags and this didnt change the output. Thank you for you help.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that log4j property to help you. The comment on the issue about that is unrelated to your issue. The point of that JIRA issue is to say that Accumulo does initialization of log4j poorly. You can try adding `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/accumulo/conf/log4j.properties` to `/opt/accumulo/conf/accumulo-env.sh` in an appropriate place (perhaps to `ACCUMULO_GENERAL_OPTS` or `ACCUMULO_OTHER_OPTS`).

Comment: The 1.2 manual for initializing log4j is here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit

Comment: Tried that and it didnt work either. Ran 1.9.2 and this issue does exist in that version of accumulo.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't exist in 1.9.2.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I am now using 1.9.2 , the errors above though are from 1.9.3

Comment: I cannot find any significant difference between 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 that would explain the error you were seeing. The only difference I can find is in the `bin/accumulo` script, the pattern we used to find the log4j jar from the `HADOOP_PREFIX` directory was changed from `-name 'log4j*.jar'` to `-regex '.*/log4j-[0-9.]*[.]jar$'`. In either case, it should have picked up the `log4j-1.2.17.jar`, and your printout shows that it did. So, I have no explanation. Sorry :(